How to clean up a graph removing redundant relationships
Hi I'm trying to process a large edges dataframe of a network. The problem is that each connected node has two relationships between them. Since loading two edges into a graph would technically be redundant as we can traverse both ways.
The network can move (a)-[DS]->(b) and (b)-[US]->(a)
the problem is that the edges we have are not labeled US or DS
Sample Graph Drawing
What I want is to only keep relationships which only traverse DS or US
I have tried this implementation of Pregel from this post.
from graphframes import GraphFrame
from graphframes.lib import Pregel
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

graphframe_checkpoint_path = f"s3a://graphframe_checkpoint/12-13-2024/"
sc.setCheckpointDir(graphframe_checkpoint_path)

# Define the schema for the vertices DataFrame
vertices_schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True)
])

# Create the vertices DataFrame with the defined schema
vertices = spark.createDataFrame([
        ("A",),
        ("B",),
        ("C",),
        ("D",),
        ("E",),
        ("F",),
        ("G",),
        ("H",),
        ("I",),
        ("J",),
        ("K",),
        ("L",),
        ("M",),
        ("N",),
        ("O",),
        ("P",),
        ("Q",)], schema=vertices_schema)

edges = spark.createDataFrame([
      ("A", "B", "connects"),
      ("B", "A", "connects"),
      ("B", "C", "connects"),
      ("B", "D", "connects"),
      ("D", "B", "connects"),
      ("C", "B", "connects"),
      ("C", "E", "connects"),
      ("E", "C", "connects"),
      ("F", "C", "connects"),
      ("C", "F", "connects"),
      ("C", "G", "connects"),
      ("G", "C", "connects"),
      ("G", "H", "connects"),
      ("G", "I", "connects"),
      ("G", "J", "connects"),
      ("H", "G", "connects"),
      ("I", "G", "connects"),
      ("J", "G", "connects"),
      ("D", "L", "connects"),
      ("L", "D", "connects"),
      ("K", "L", "connects"),
      ("L", "K", "connects"),
      ("L", "M", "connects"),
      ("M", "L", "connects"),
      ("M", "Q", "connects"),
      ("M", "N", "connects"),
      ("M", "O", "connects"),
      ("M", "P", "connects"),
      ("Q", "M", "connects"),
      ("N", "M", "connects"),
      ("O", "M", "connects"),
      ("P", "M", "connects"),
    ], ["dst", "src", "relationship"])

g = GraphFrame(vertices,edges)

vertColSchema = StructType()\
      .add("dist", DoubleType())\
      .add("node", StringType())\
      .add("path", ArrayType(StringType(), True))

def vertexProgram(vd, msg):
    if msg == None or vd.__getitem__(0) < msg.__getitem__(0):
        return (vd.__getitem__(0), vd.__getitem__(1), vd.__getitem__(2))
    else:
        return (msg.__getitem__(0), vd.__getitem__(1), msg.__getitem__(2))

vertexProgramUdf = F.udf(vertexProgram, vertColSchema)

def sendMsgToDst(src, dst):
    srcDist = src.__getitem__(0)
    dstDist = dst.__getitem__(0)
    if srcDist < (dstDist - 1):
        return (srcDist + 1, src.__getitem__(1), src.__getitem__(2) + [dst.__getitem__(1)])
    else:
        return None

sendMsgToDstUdf = F.udf(sendMsgToDst, vertColSchema)

def aggMsgs(agg):
    shortest_dist = sorted(agg, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[0]
    return (shortest_dist.__getitem__(0), shortest_dist.__getitem__(1), shortest_dist.__getitem__(2))

aggMsgsUdf = F.udf(aggMsgs, vertColSchema)

result = (
    g.pregel.withVertexColumn(
        colName = "vertCol",

        initialExpr = F.when(
            F.col("id") == "D",
            F.struct(F.lit(0.0), F.col("id"), F.array(F.col("id")))
        ).otherwise(
            F.struct(F.lit(float("inf")), F.col("id"), F.array(F.lit("")))
        ).cast(vertColSchema),

        updateAfterAggMsgsExpr = vertexProgramUdf(F.col("vertCol"), Pregel.msg())
    )
    .sendMsgToDst(sendMsgToDstUdf(F.col("src.vertCol"), Pregel.dst("vertCol")))
    .aggMsgs(aggMsgsUdf(F.collect_list(Pregel.msg())))
    .setMaxIter(5)    ## This should be greater than the max depth of the graph
    .setCheckpointInterval(1)
    .run()
)

df = result.select("vertCol.node", "vertCol.path").repartition(1)
df.show()
# +----+---------------+
# |node|           path|
# +----+---------------+
# |   A|      [D, B, A]|
# |   B|         [D, B]|
# |   C|      [D, B, C]|
# |   D|            [D]|
# |   E|   [D, B, C, E]|
# |   F|   [D, B, C, F]|
# |   G|   [D, B, C, G]|
# |   H|[D, B, C, G, H]|
# |   I|[D, B, C, G, I]|
# |   J|[D, B, C, G, J]|
# |   K|      [D, L, K]|
# |   L|         [D, L]|
# |   M|      [D, L, M]|
# |   N|   [D, L, M, N]|
# |   O|   [D, L, M, O]|
# |   P|   [D, L, M, P]|
# |   Q|   [D, L, M, Q]|
# +----+---------------+

final = df.select('node', F.concat_ws('->', F.reverse('path')).alias('path'))
final.show()

# +----+-------------+
# |node|         path|
# +----+-------------+
# |   A|      A->B->D|
# |   B|         B->D|
# |   C|      C->B->D|
# |   D|            D|
# |   E|   E->C->B->D|
# |   F|   F->C->B->D|
# |   G|   G->C->B->D|
# |   H|H->G->C->B->D|
# |   I|I->G->C->B->D|
# |   J|J->G->C->B->D|
# |   K|      K->L->D|
# |   L|         L->D|
# |   M|      M->L->D|
# |   N|   N->M->L->D|
# |   O|   O->M->L->D|
# |   P|   P->M->L->D|
# |   Q|   Q->M->L->D|
# +----+-------------+

D was chosen as an id to see what would happen if I had started somewhere in the middle but ideally I would be providing id A since I know what my starting point is.
Although it worked well for the sample dataset and depth of 10.
Applying this implementation to a GraphFrame of ~70mil nodes with depth of 200 does not work and is not able to process the whole data.
Assuming I'm taking up too much memory to store each path is not efficient.
the dataset was already filtered using connectedComponents to only get components that contain starting id's.
200 max depth was chosen as a test but it is possible we have longer chains.
Have you ever had a similar problem and if so how did you approach it?
One of the proposed solutions below works well when we assume ID's are start from A and that determines the rank of the value but seems to not work if we switch around vertex G with vertex L.

Actually, you problem is called as graph orientation problem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(graph_theory)
If you have two edges between nodes, e.g. A to B and B to A.
We need to find a consistent way to convert into a directed acyclic graph.
There exists a simple method to do this. Assign numeric ids to the vertices.
Then keep only those edges which go from lower_numeric_id to larger_numeric_id
The following code achieves just that very simply.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType


def orient_graph_spark(edges_data):

    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("GraphOrientation") \
        .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "10") .getOrCreate()


    edge_schema = StructType([
        StructField("source", StringType(), True),
        StructField("target", StringType(), True),
        StructField("relationship", StringType(), True)
    ])

    edges_df = spark.createDataFrame(edges_data, schema=edge_schema).repartition(10)  # Adjust number of partitions based on data size


    vertices_df = edges_df.select(col("source").alias("vertex")) \
        .union(edges_df.select(col("target").alias("vertex"))) \
        .distinct() \
        .orderBy("vertex") \
        .coalesce(1)  # Coalesce to 1 partition since we need global ordering


    vertices_with_ids = vertices_df \
        .withColumn("vertex_id", monotonically_increasing_id()) \
        .orderBy("vertex")

    # broadcast the vertex mapping as it's typically small
    vertices_with_ids = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(
        vertices_with_ids.collect()
    )

    # broadcast variable to dictionary for efficient lookup
    vertex_to_id = {row.vertex: row.vertex_id for row in vertices_with_ids.value}

    # udf for ID lookup
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

    vertex_to_id_udf = udf(lambda x: int(vertex_to_id.get(x, -1)), IntegerType())


    edges_with_ids = edges_df \
        .withColumn("source_id", vertex_to_id_udf(col("source"))) \
        .withColumn("target_id", vertex_to_id_udf(col("target")))

    # source_id < target_id
    oriented_edges = edges_with_ids \
        .filter(col("source_id") < col("target_id")) \
        .select("source", "target") \
        .distinct() \
        .orderBy("source", "target")

    return oriented_edges, vertex_to_id


def main():

    edges = [
        ("A", "B", "connects"),
        ("B", "A", "connects"),
        ("B", "C", "connects"),
        ("B", "D", "connects"),
        ("D", "B", "connects"),
        ("C", "B", "connects"),
        ("C", "E", "connects"),
        ("E", "C", "connects"),
        ("F", "C", "connects"),
        ("C", "F", "connects"),
        ("C", "G", "connects"),
        ("G", "C", "connects"),
        ("G", "H", "connects"),
        ("G", "I", "connects"),
        ("G", "J", "connects"),
        ("H", "G", "connects"),
        ("I", "G", "connects"),
        ("J", "G", "connects"),
        ("D", "L", "connects"),
        ("L", "D", "connects"),
        ("K", "L", "connects"),
        ("L", "K", "connects"),
        ("L", "M", "connects"),
        ("M", "L", "connects"),
        ("M", "Q", "connects"),
        ("M", "N", "connects"),
        ("M", "O", "connects"),
        ("M", "P", "connects"),
        ("Q", "M", "connects"),
        ("N", "M", "connects"),
        ("O", "M", "connects"),
        ("P", "M", "connects")
    ]

    oriented_edges_df, vertex_mapping = orient_graph_spark(edges)

    print("Vertex ID mapping:")
    for vertex, vid in sorted(vertex_mapping.items()):
        print(f"{vertex}: {vid}")

    print("\nOriented edges:")
    oriented_edges_df.show(truncate=False)

    print("\nStatistics:")
    print(f"Original edges: {len(edges)}")
    print(f"Oriented edges: {oriented_edges_df.count()}")
    print(f"Reduction: {((len(edges) - oriented_edges_df.count()) / len(edges) * 100):.1f}%")

    SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output is as follows :
Vertex ID mapping:
A: 0
B: 1
C: 2
D: 3
E: 4
F: 5
G: 6
H: 7
I: 8
J: 9
K: 10
L: 11
M: 12
N: 13
O: 14
P: 15
Q: 16

Oriented edges:
+------+------+
|source|target|
+------+------+
|A     |B     |
|B     |C     |
|B     |D     |
|C     |E     |
|C     |F     |
|C     |G     |
|D     |L     |
|G     |H     |
|G     |I     |
|G     |J     |
|K     |L     |
|L     |M     |
|M     |N     |
|M     |O     |
|M     |P     |
|M     |Q     |
+------+------+


Statistics:
Original edges: 32
Oriented edges: 16
Reduction: 50.0%


Hi Thank you so much for your response!!! Happy Holidays!
I'm currently away from my computer so haven't got a chance to try it, but do you think this will work on a large edge dataset which contains many subgraphs?

You can try it. First ensure the end result is correct. Check indeed that is what you want.

I added another dataset into the table, same graph 1-12 id and it worked. Also this seems to work when IDs are sortable and we assume A is the starting vertex. Doesn't seem to work for ID's which don't follow the the pattern. For Example replacing vertex G for vertex L we see a reduction of 56%

The condition between two vertex P and Q, there should be two edges (P,Q,connects) and (Q,P,connects).

Sorry a bit confused by that. The original graph doesn't have P connecting to Q. they both only connect to M.

The comment wasn't related to the data you provided in question. Just take any two vertex Y and Z. Then the data should have both the edges for it to work correct. i.e. Y connects Z and Z connects Y.
